# Editable character sheet that handles multiple BAB

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-sheets

I've been playing a ranger class in Dungeon & Dragons 3.5 using [This character sheet](http://www.theagencystar.com/download_files/Interactive_DnD_3.5_Character_Sheet.pdf).

A lot of the fields auto calculate (like skills and modifiers), it's a pdf so I can have it offline and still edit it, but it doesn't work too well when I have multiple Base Attack Bonus.

[Myth Weavers](http://www.myth-weavers.com/) uses their own character sheet that still calculates fields AND works with multiple Base Attack Bonus. But has to stay online for it to be edited or viewed.

I'm looking for an offline (preferably pdf) character sheet that can calculate modifiers and have multiple Base Attack Bonus. Is there such a character sheet?

Comment: Read this as *edible*; the world is sadder for the truth.

Comment: What do you mean by “multiple base attack bonus”? Having multiple attacks due to high base attack bonus (e.g. +6/+1)? Having levels in multiple classes with different base attack bonus progressions? Having separate base attack bonuses used for different attacks (handling *divine power*, maybe)?

Comment: As in having multiple attacks due to high base attack bonus (+6/+1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PCGen](http://pcgen.org/) is a character generator.

> PCGen is a FREE multi-platform Open Source character generator and maintenance program for role-playing games. It supports the d20 RPG system and includes data sets based on material from Wizards of the Coast (D&D), Paizo Publishing, and many other publishers.

For 3.5e, it only includes the SRD, but you can enter other content as homebrew.

It reminds you what still needs to be done to complete (or level up) your character, and you can export the character sheet as HTML, PDF, or print.

It can include special attacks on the output sheet (eg Rapid Shot, Manyshot, etc).

Answer (score 2):

What we use for 3.5 is HeroForge.  It's not a simple, fillable character sheet.  It's a Microsoft Excel workbook that covers *everything*.  You fill in multiple pages worth of details and it computes everything and generates a spell sheet for you.  It's all offline.  There's a page where you can tick off buffs or other effects you have active on you, and it will recompute the appropriate numbers for you.

This is an old project that the owner stopped maintaining.  [Someone else has taken it over.](https://sites.google.com/site/heroforgeanew/home)  I haven't re-downloaded it since the new owner has taken over, so I can't vouch for the new version, but if you want a character management tool that covers everything, you will probably find what you're looking for in HeroForge.